# Show suggestion from different indexes of elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Suppose I have two indexes in elasticsearch. First `names` contains five values `Ram, Shyam, Hari, Dipu, Kishan` and second `profession` contains five values like `teacher, driver, doctor, bank manager, salesman`. When someone types `Ra`, I want to show suggestions like

```
Ram is teacher
Ram is driver
Ram is doctor
Ram is bank manager
Ram is salesman
```

Similarly when someone types `Har`, I want to show

```
Hari is teacher
Hari is driver
Hari is doctor
Hari is bank manager
Hari is salesman
```

I don't want to store every possible combination.
Also suppose user is looking for `Ram is a doctor at Raman Hospital since 2002.` Here `Ram, doctor, Raman Hospital, 2002` belongs to different-different indexes. When user types `Ram` I want to show suggestions as `Ram is a teacher at Basic Boys School Since 2002`, `Ram is salesman at HUL since 2006`. And if there is one more guy with name `Raman` then `Raman is driver at Ola since 2012` should also be shown as suggestion. For such searches is there any good approach available or I have to work on that?

Mapping:

```
PUT name
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "contexts": [
                        { 
                            "name": "userid",
                            "type": "category"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Indexing:

```
POST name/_doc/
{
    "suggest": {
        "input": ["BHANU PRAKASH"],
        "contexts": {
            "userid": ["99569858","99156661","90273758","6598242461","65910563"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you need to do two searches, first an seachr in "names", than with the choosen value a search in "profession"

Comment: With two searches it's fine. But if I want to show `Ram is a doctor at Raman Hospital since 2002`. Here `Ram`, `doctor`, `Raman Hospital`, `2002` belongs to different-different indexes. When user types `Ram` I want to show suggestions as `Ram is a teacher at Basic Boys School Since 2002`, `Ram is salesman at HUL since 2006`. And if there is one more guy with name `Raman` then `Raman is driver at Ola since 2012` should also be shown as suggestion. For such searches is there any good approach available or I have to work on that?

Comment: good point, I'm sorry I'm not so into elasticsearch to tell you if there is an solution for that... I'll give this question a vote up... maybe you should include the additonal requirements you just wrote in the question itselfe by edtiting the question

Comment: Can you provide sample indexes and documents  ?

Comment: @Yeikel Both Mapping and Index are added in the question. All the indexes have same kind of format.

Comment: @Lars-OlofKreim how do I track for second search in javascript?

Comment: basically I would suggest to rather combine both searches in backend not in frontend